# Set redux state with firebase on(), or set it from the front end on every change?

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux

I have an array of objects. The objects are on firebase. I need the objects in the front end, and i need them in the redux state. The objects are editable, and deletable, the array is expandable in the front end by the user. The application needs to be real time with multiple devices used on the same time. If a change happens on device-1, it need to appear in device-2 immediately. The right method for this is to listen if any change happened in the database, and set it as the redux state. Which is the right practice? Create actions for the changes (edit, add, or delete), even if the whole state of the array will be updated by `on()`? Or it will be unnecessary, the `on()` will do all the work?